# SSIS OLE DB Command to Update a Table

Tags: ssis

```
    DECLARE @FK_Thread INT ; 
    DECLARE @AccountName NVARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @AccountCode NVARCHAR(128);

    SET @FK_Thread = ? ;
    SET @AccountName = ? ; /*value that I want for the column to use in update */
    SET @AccountCode = ?; 

    /*I wanted to Update a Table using SSIS OLD DB Command */

    UPDATE acc
    /*whatever the new accountname I want to set this to update in this column*/ 
    SET  gls.AccountName =@AccoutName  
    FROM Account acc
    INNER JOIN  Thread th
    ON acc.FK_Thread= th.PK_Thread
    INNER JOIN POST p 
    P.PK_Post = th.FK_Post
    WHERE 
    th.FK_Thread = @FK_Thread AND acc.AccountCode = @AccoutCode
    GROUP BY p.PostCode asc ;  
    //Here I also want to filter for with my BatchID which is a user defined variable 
    (DT_I4)@[User::BatchKey]
```

One more thing when I do a straight Update 
LIKE

```
 UPDATE Account SET AccountName= ? 
    WHERE 
    AccoutCode = ?
    AND 
    FK_Thread = ? // This works but I cannot group by PostCode in order to  filter and show appropriate error message
```

I have turned DelayValidation To FALSE before I was getting "Cannot Bound Parameter"
The Error I am Getting 
[image]

Comment: Do you get an error when you run the update in SSMS (without using SSIS)?

Comment: When I Press Refresh in the OLE DB Command . Refresh Button in the Screen Shot . Thank you

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  I'm asking you to run your query in SSMS, and let us know if you get an error, and what the error is.

Comment: OLE DB Command is one of the Data Flow Item in Pakage. Currently it is throwing an Error Message. I cannot Build my pakage if one of the item in my Control flow is throwing an error message .

Comment: The Update Query works when i try it in SQL Server (SSMS).

Comment: In that case, there must be some error in the way you are building the query in SSIS.   Use profiler to see what SQL Command is actually being sent from SSIS to your database.

Comment: Thank you i will do that and see

Comment: For the complex query, `GROUP BY p.PostCode asc ;` is invalid SQL

Comment: If the code sample is a direct paste, there are also some typos in the variable names.